# could not find function "C5.0 r using C50

Tags: r, decision-tree, c5.0

I would like to use C5.0 but with few error
this is the code:

```
library(modeldata)
data(credit_data)
set.seed(2411)
in_train <- sample(1:nrow(credit_data), size = 3000)
train_data <- credit_data[ in_train,]
test_data  <- credit_data[-in_train,]
install.packages("C50")
library(C50)
tree_mod <- C5.0(x = train_data[, vars], y = train_data$Status)
tree_mod
```

I get the following error
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘C50’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):

```
Error in C5.0(x = train_data[, vars], y = train_data$Status) : 
  could not find function "C5.0"
```

Comment: Your code and the data provided in the website is not matching.

Comment: Try installing the development version using the following code: `library("devtools");
install_github("topepo/C5.0");`

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/code/samueljoseph502/risky-bank-loans/data

Comment: This is the match site to the code

Comment: tried library("devtools"); install_github("topepo/C5.0") , it didnt work

Comment: Your code here doesn't actually load the package you're asking about (C5.0). Did you do that and just not include it in your question?

Comment: I have the install.packages("C50") before , but now  I added it to the code

Comment: Try restarting your R session. It isn't really clear from your question, but that's the type of error that can come after installing packages. Have you read through the package docs and been able to run their code?

Comment: I tried to restart but with no success, this is the error for library (C50) Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘C50’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Cubist’
In addition: Warning message:

Comment: Your error message is telling you you're missing a package. Did you install that package as well?

Comment: I installed the C50, this is still what I get  : Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘C50’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Cubist’

Comment: ’  AND when trying to install Cubist I get     Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/Cubist_0.4.1.zip'

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem
remotes::install_github("topepo/Cubist", upgrade = FALSE)